# Update dynamically changing number of records in SQL Server database using a single connection

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, promise, azure-sql-database

I am using `mssql` node module to query a SQL Server database.

```
var update = {"id":"1","status":"active"};

sql.connect(config.then(pool => {            
    return pool.request()
        .query(query)
}).then(result => {
    console.dir(result)
    if(result)
        pool.close();
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

But now, I need to update multiple records, the number of records to update changes dynamically by opening only one connection. In the below example, there are 2 devices that needs to be updated. The number of update records change depending on the request.

```
update =[{"id":"1","status":"active"},{"id":"1","status":"active"}]

var update = req.body.update;
var len = update.length;

for (i = 0; i < update.length; i++) { 
    var query = "UPDATE faults SET current_status = "+ status +" WHERE id = " + update[i].id ;
}
update();
```

From my understanding there is not multiple statement execution option like in MySql in SQL Server.

Can someone help me with the approach here?

Comment: SQL Server supports multiple DML statements in one batch. Please read about SQL driver for node.js https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks, used connection.execSqlBatch(request) and its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `connection.execSqlBatch(request)` to achieve this.

[Tedious](https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html#function_execSqlBatch)